# Why does this code in C++ give me a runtime error?

Tags: c++, char, runtime, newline

I am attempting to take char input from the user, and typecasting it to integer, such the A = 1; B = 2...Z = 26; and store it in an array. 
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
char input; 
int f[8]; 
int counter; 

for(counter = 0; counter <= 8; counter++){ 
cin >> input; 
 f[counter] = (int)input - 64; 
if(input == '\n') break;
} 

cout << f[0] << endl; }
```

the `if(input = '\n') break;` line gives me an error. I am trying to break the loop on entering a new line. What's wrong in that? I am attempting to do this as I am taking 2 lines as input(which isn't important information here).

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds. `counter <= 8` should be `counter <  8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this code in C++ give me a runtime error?

1. Because you don't use safe high-level facilities like `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of **error-prone raw arrays**.
2. The error you made causes **undefined behaviour**. `int f[8];` is an array with 8 elements, indexed from 0 to 7, yet later on, in your loop your condition says `counter <= 8`, which *includes* 8. It should be `counter < 8`. Accessing `f[8]` is undefined behaviour.
3. Undefined behaviour means the compiler can build **any behaviour** into your program, including a crash with an error message.

Here's a safer, modern version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() { 
    std::array<int, 8> f;

    for(auto&& element : f) {
        char input; 
        std::cin >> input; 
        element = static_cast<int>(input) - 'A' + 1;
    }

    std::cout << f[0] << "\n";
}
```

Some changes:

- Used `std::array`.
- Replaced C-style cast with `static_cast`.
- Used a C++11 range-based `for` loop. No need to hard-code the array's size in the loop condition.
- Removed `using namespace std;`, which is almost always bad practice and which beginners should not use at all.
- Removed your `\n` check, which will never work because `std::cin >> input;` disregards all whitespace. You will have to use `std::getline` to get the behaviour you want. In fact, you will want to do this anyway to get some actual error handling into your program.
- Minimised scope of local variables.
- The character A is not guaranteed to have the integer value 65. It's safer (and more readable) to write `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

The program is giving you a runtime error because your Array loop is out of bounds. `for(counter = 0; counter <= 8; counter++)`.
You should use `for(counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)`.

Answer (score 0):

`operator >>` here skips whitespace by default, which includes newline characters - so you will never see one.

To avoid that you need to use [`cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). There are other alternatives - you could use `getline` to read a line at a time and then parse the `string` you get.

Fixing your subscript out of bounds would be a good idea too, of course.